# Kivy crashes instantly when I run a dropdown list program on Python3.7

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown, python-3.7

I'm having some issues with kivy *once more.* Whenever I run the following program, python instantly crashes, the window that gets opened goes blank and I have no choice but to close it. Been trying to fix this for an hour or so but can't seem to get anything done.

Also, I get no error in traceback.

Thanks in advance for the help

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from os import listdir


class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.layout = FloatLayout()
        self.fileList = []

    def dropdown(self):
        self.musDir = listdir(r'C://Users//danburnier//Desktop//PythonPrograms','r')
        for file in self.musDir:
            if file.endswith('.py'):
                btn = Button(text=str(file[:-3]),size_hint_y=None,height=44)

                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn:self.select(btn.text))

                self.add_widget(btn)

class DropDownApp(App):

    def build(self):

        mainButton = Button(text='Touch me.',size_hint=(None,None))
        mainButton.bind(on_release=d.open)
        d.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainButton, 'text', x))
        return CustomDropDown()

d = CustomDropDown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropDownApp().run()
```

Edit:

I don't know if it can help, but running it on Thonny (on a raspberry pi 4) I get the following traceback:

```
[INFO] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-03- 
03_19.txt

[INFO] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc1, git-Unknown, 20200303

[INFO] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/kivy/__init__.py"

[INFO] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 

[GCC 8.2.0]

[INFO] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"

[INFO] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded

[INFO] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.1

[INFO] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, 
img_ffpyplayer (img_gif ignored)

[INFO] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system

[INFO] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>

[INFO] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 Mesa 19.2.0-rc1'>

[INFO] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>

[INFO] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'V3D 4.2'>

[INFO] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1

[INFO] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>

[INFO] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>

[INFO] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>

[INFO] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

[INFO] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

[INFO] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
```

```
Backend terminated or disconnected.Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0xb6fccad0 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1309 in add_widget
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 927 in _run_prepare
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949 in run
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Music21/ProgFin/ScrollMenu22.py", line 34 in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1211 in _execute_prepared_user_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1139 in wrapper
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1152 in wrapper
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 1198 in execute_source
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 840 in _execute_source
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 826 in _execute_file
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 387 in _cmd_Run
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 195 in handle_command
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 137 in mainloop
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend_launcher.py", line 76 in <module> Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is totally wrong and full of mistakes. First, DropDown should be opened to be shown. You don't open it. Secondly, your CustomDropDown class inherits DropDown. Why? You don't override any of its methods, what did you try to do? Thirdly, you have a function in that class and you don't call it. It won't run by itself. Fourthly, you have a few objects of that class, you do something with object in `d` variable but then you are returning a new, blank object. If you returned `d` it wouldn't work either, but pay attention to that kind of stuff. You created layout and you don't use it.

Maybe that will work as you wanted:

```
class DropDownTest(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DropDownTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (1, 1)

    def createdd(self):
        dropdown = DropDown()
        musDir = listdir(r'C://Users//danburnier//Desktop//PythonPrograms','r')
        for file in musDir:
            if file.endswith('.py'):
                btn = Button(text=str(file[:-3]),size_hint_y=None,height=44)
                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
                self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton = Button(text='Open DropDown', size_hint=(1, 1), on_release=dropdown.open)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
        self.add_widget(mainbutton)

class DropDownApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.ddtest = DropDownTest()
        self.ddtest.createdd()
        return self.ddtest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropDownApp().run()
```

You can put something in functions but don't forget to call it.

Comment: So, this works in the sense that it no longer crashes, which is definitely a good step forwards!

However, nothing is displayed. Is there a special to add the dropdown to the display or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for improving my mistakes and sorry for that, English is not my first language :D

Comment: @DGGB let's try to inherit BoxLayout instead of FloatLayout and add size hints to layout and mainbutton. I've edited code in my answer, check it.

Comment: Been fiddling around with your modifications, but it still won't display anything for some reason.

Oh and don't worry about any english errors, happens to the best of us :D

Comment: Also, 'self' doesn't work anymore since it's not in a function anymore so I've replaced them by the 'dropdown' variable anytime it appeared.

Comment: @DGGB self means BoxLayout here, ok, try to put it in function as I did

Comment: Hey, it works now! I just have to fix some stuff, but it's working. Thanks a lot, you honestly taught me so much just now !!